# Duplicate question of...?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, deleted-questions

This question:

[Putting the integration bounds below/above the integration operator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/putting-the-integration-bounds-below-above-the-integration-operator/67063)

is labeled as duplicate. However it doesn't point to any other question? How is it possible? Was the question it was pointing to deleted? How can we prevent that from happening?

Comment: That question was closed.  (Closed questions can be seen by participants whose reputation is above a certain amount.)  Unfortunately, the cited question was in the list of "often referenced questions", but since it had been closed as a duplicate, I updated the list with the referenced duplicate, after checking that it was equivalent.  The newly referenced question is [Show inline math as if it were display math (and vice versa)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824).

Comment: I can clearly see the original question, as well as the suggested duplicate; I'm sure everyone would be able to see it.

Comment: This looks like an older way of marking duplicates. The duplicate link is in the **Possible Duplicate:** quote box. Maybe not as intuitive as the new setup where the duplicate is shown directly in the closure box and not inline in the question, but still visible if you read on (though I must admit that the text in the close box is a bit confusing now...)

Comment: I expect that all new closures will show the duplicate in the close box. But I don't think questions closed under the old scheme will be updated (I assume if that had been easy SX would have done that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can we prevent that from happening?

This happens for *all* old duplicate closures, look e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate%3A1+lastactive%3A..2013-02-03) for more examples. Questions closed after February 4th, 2013 always show a link to the so-called 'original' in their banner.

Back then, the duplicate banner was edited into the post itself:

[image]

You can start to [edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/67053/edit) the post to see the 'source code' of the banner. There is no 'official' link from this question to the original, hence the blue banner stays empty.

The only way to solve this is to reopen the question, and close it again as a duplicate (and edit out the original banner). We do this sometimes on Meta Stack Exchange (there are many people with [dupehammers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/295232) there); on main sites, basically only ♦ moderators can do that. But as you can see, they would have to do that on many posts. I don't think that's an option.