# Closed as duplicate, but only possible duplicate linked

Tags: bug, duplicates

I noticed that [How to fit a large figure to page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32886/how-to-fit-a-large-figure-to-page) is marked as duplicate, but no duplicate post is shown, only a *possible* duplicate:

[image: screenshot of the linked post]

If this is intended behaviour, the colon should be removed and reworded.

While searching for possible duplicates of this bug, I ran across [an instance of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87104/closed-as-an-exact-duplicate-possible-duplicate) on the Meta site. Perhaps it exists on all of SE? I haven't checked.

Comment: I think you've possibly found the duplicate :) on the meta site. This language is network wide, so we can't change it. It's trying to say that the linked question is possibly (and since 5 users voted to close, most likely) a duplicate. It depends on the logical meaning of 'possible' but certainly not its usual pragmatic use.

Comment: @AlanMunn no, I am referring to the fact that the text "This question already has an answer here:" is not in fact followed by a link to a question

Comment: Maybe https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8739/35864 is a better duplicate.

Comment: Yep, that's the one! Flagged as dupe (that's a new one :'))